# How to prevent cargo from swinging inside fairings?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm using [Ferram Aerospace Research](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/20451-0-23-Ferram-Aerospace-Research-v0-13x1-experimental-out-3-15-14) to add some realism to drag. But this makes me to use fairings for my payload.

Sad thing is, my payload swings. A lot. I tried both KW Rocketry and Procedural Fairings but both express the same behaviour. Without internal struts I can't make it to an orbit sometimes.

Placing internal struts is next to impossible, so is there any other way to have cargo secured? I know that [mission failures caused by payload fairings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payload_fairing#Mission_failures_caused_by_payload_fairings) happens in real life, but I think I had enough of them to feel realism already. There are some patents for securing cargo inside fairing (I mean real life USA and EU patents) - is there any way to get the same in KSP?

I mean, for example, something like CFLR here:

[image]

[Article with this image](https://spaceflightnow.com/atlas/av003/030715preview.html)

> To give the fairing structural support during the ascent, the "Centaur Forward Load Reactor" deck has been designed by Contraves. This aluminum ring extends from the Centaur to the fairing's inner wall. It separates in two halves moments after the fairing is jettisoned during launch.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question and many other KSP questions is:

### MORE STRUTS

Simple as that. Before placing the nose cone, place symmetrical struts from your payload to the fairing wall. I assume you're using fairing walls and not just the nose cone because your payload is large enough to swing.

I did this and was able to lift a large lander with enough fuel to land and return from Duna without it swinging.

If you're still getting swing consider assigning SAS to a control group, to disable it during launch.

Comment: I use Procedural Fairings, and they are created as a single element, nose cone and walls. Or Kw Rocketry fairings, and these are built from nose down. I can put struts there, it is just painful to do.

Comment: I use KW and that is the easiest way. You could zoom in through the fairings and try to do it that way, good luck. Removing the nose cone is for sure the easiest. The only other way is quantum struts.

Answer (score -2):

The only way is to make the cargo rigid enough it doesn't swing. And that means strutting usually (or simply make the cargo smaller, launching it in several launches and docking it together for example).

Comment: Cargo itself is rigid enough. What I lack is what's signed as CFLR [here](http://spaceflightnow.com/atlas/av003/images/030715atlas5500art.jpg) - rings to hold it in place.